# Share intent is showing only messaging & bluetooth app. How can I have more options/apps to share with?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to add a share feature from within my app.

I want to share the link to my app.

This is what I've done so far:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutShareAppContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.share_app_container);
        linearLayoutShareAppContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via..."));
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
        });
```

**The problem is that on clicking the share text (layout) only bluetooth & messaging app is shown to share with.**

**What I want is to have more apps like WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter etc to share with.**

As I'm a beginner, I have no idea what to do!

Please let know.

Thanks.

Comment: The code that you have will display Apps like WhatsApp, Facebook & Twitter if they are installed on the device.

Comment: @Suhas they are installed, but they aren't showing up!!

Comment: does apps like, Facebook, Twitter, hangouts are installed in your device..!! because, Intent.ACTION_SEND picks the relevant apps that are installed in your device.

Answer (score 0):

Same as my experienced problem here:
[Android: chooser dialog skipped while sharing text type data to external app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491138/android-chooser-dialog-skipped-while-sharing-text-type-data-to-external-app)

1. Either there's no other suitable app in your device or
2. You have to clear/restore your default app settings ( e.g.Phone Settings> Manage apps>Reset app preferences)

Comment: I resolved that issue, the problem now is that suppose you choose WhatsApp to share with & then when you click on a contact...all disappears & my app starts again without sharing anything.

Comment: what do you mean by "all disappears" ? that can involve more possible reasons in code/device, try open a new topic & post your code to discuss about it or go through a code debugging first maybe

Comment: I meant to say that on clicking on contact nothing got shared and I was returned back to my app.

Comment: I tried your above code and has no problem in sharing the content

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "choose one"));`